# Two conditionally independent variables are conditional independent given $F$

Tags: conditional-probability

Suppose X and Y are conditionally independent given Z. Suppose X and Z are conditionally independent given $F$,where $F\subset \sigma(Z)$. Prove that X and Y are conditionally independent given $F$.